# Compiling GWT in Jenkins

Tags: gwt, ant, jenkins

I'm trying to set up Jenkins to build a GWT project, but I got this error

```
gwt-compile-module:
 [java] Jul 01, 2014 2:08:59 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
 [java] INFO: Created user preferences directory.
 [java] Loading inherited module 'OBFUSCATE'
 [java]    [ERROR] Unable to find 'OBFUSCATE.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

I have gwt-user.jar, gwt-dev.jar, validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar and validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar in the class path.

OBFUSCATE.gwt.xml must be some GWT base module but cannot find it anywhere.

Here is the snippet from build.xml:

```
<target name="gwt-compile-module" description="Build one GWT module - java to javascript">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>                
            <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
            <path refid="project.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024M"/>
        <arg value="-optimize"/>
        <arg value="${optimize}"/>
        <arg value="-localWorkers"/>
        <arg value="${localWorkers}"/>
        <arg value="-war" />
        <arg value="${gwt.output.dir}" />
        <arg value="${draftCompile}" />
        <arg value="${gwt.modules}${gwt.module}"/>
        <arg line="-style OBFUSCATE"/>
     </java>
 </target>
```

Comment: Apparently the issue is caused by the argument '-style OBFUSCATE' passed to the GWT compiler.
That works fine when I run the ant build in eclipse, but when run in Jenkins GWT thinks it's a module.

Comment: Different versions of Ant having different behavior? (assuming you're using Ant) Post the snippet from your build script that calls the GWT Compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should rearrange your `arg` options and place `<arg line="-style OBFUSCATE"/>` **before** `<arg value="${gwt.modules}${gwt.module}"/>`:

```
<arg line="-style OBFUSCATE"/>
<arg value="${gwt.modules}${gwt.module}"/>
```

Comment: Moving that line as you suggested works. I just don't get why in Eclipse is fine either way.